# save array of strings in database by using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i try to add an array to my database lately so I want to add new collection in MongoDB I guess I have follow the good road to create new collection I had did the three file to create new collection, the model of Schema , the router of collection and finally I connected to the server. but when I want to see my new collection inside my database I didn't found it.please help me to fix my problem:
this is all my code:

```
server.js file:
import express from "express";

import mongoose from "mongoose";
import userRouter from "./routers/userRouter.js";
import productRouter from "./routers/productRouter.js";
import categoriesRouter  from "./routers/productRouter.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config()
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
mongoose.connect( process.env.MONGODB_URL || "mongodb://localhost/myshop",{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.send("server is ready!")
});

app.use("/api/users", userRouter);
app.use("/api/products", productRouter);
app.use("/api/categories", categoriesRouter);
app.use((err, req, res, next)=> {
    res.status(500).send({message: err.message})
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

```
data.js file:
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
const data = {
    users: [
        {
    name: "Borhen",
    email: "borem3110@gmail.com",
    password: bcrypt.hashSync('1234', 8),
    isAdmin: true
},
{
    name: "Morad",
    email: "momo@gmail.com",
    password: bcrypt.hashSync('1080', 8),
    isAdmin: false
}
    ],
    products: [
        {
           
            name: "Aprilia sr 101",
            image: "../images/p1.jpg",
            category: "mecanic",
            subCategory: "bike",
            price: 18645,
            numInStock: 21,
            brand: "Aprilia",
            rating: 4.8,
            numReviews: 105,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
           
            name: "Aprilia cr 150",
            image: "../images/p2.jpg",
            category: "mecanic",
            subCategory: "bike",
            price: 1865,
            numInStock: 35,
            brand: "Aprilia",
            rating: 4,
            numReviews: 103,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
           
            name: "Harley Davidson",
            image: "../images/p3.jpg",
            category: "mecanic",
            subCategory: "bike",
            price: 286745,
            numInStock: 7,
            brand: "ApriliaHarley",
            rating: 4.5,
            numReviews: 204,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
            
            name: "Honda cbr1001",
            image: "../images/p4.jpg",
            category: "mecanic",
            subCategory: "bike",
            price: 27655,
            numInStock: 6,
            brand: "Honda",
            rating: 5,
            numReviews: 105,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
           
            name: "Asus",
            image: "../images/p5.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "pc",
            price: 1200,
            numInStock: 36,
            brand: "Asus",
            rating: 4,
            numReviews: 135,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
            
            name: "Hp pavillon",
            image: "../images/p6.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "pc",
            price: 965,
            numInStock: 0,
            brand: "Hp",
            rating: 4.8,
            numReviews: 10,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
           
            name: "Lenovo 1500",
            image: "../images/p7.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "pc",
            price: 1345,
            numInStock: 41,
            brand: "Lenovo",
            rating: 5,
            numReviews: 98,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
            
            name: "Hp Compaq",
            image: "../images/p8.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "pc",
            price: 899,
            numInStock: 6,
            brand: "Hp",
            rating: 4.3,
            numReviews: 185,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
           
            name: "Toshiba 1400",
            image: "../images/p9.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "pc",
            price: 1269,
            numInStock: 0,
            brand: "Toshiba",
            rating: 5,
            numReviews: 123,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
            
            name: "Huawei 35k",
            image: "../images/p10.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "phone",
            price: 1045,
            numInStock: 18,
            brand: "Huawei",
            rating: 4.9,
            numReviews: 113,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
            
            name: "Iphone 5",
            image: "../images/p11.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "phone",
            price: 1205,
            numInStock: 46,
            brand: "Huawei",
            rating: 4.7,
            numReviews: 85,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
            
            name: "Redmi n9",
            image: "../images/p12.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "phone",
            price: 1254,
            numInStock: 2,
            brand: "Redmi",
            rating: 4.6,
            numReviews: 175,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
            
            name: "Samsung galaxy z",
            image: "../images/p13.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "phone",
            price: 1045,
            numInStock: 19,
            brand: "Samsung",
            rating: 4.5,
            numReviews: 175,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
            
            name: "Samsung s4",
            image: "../images/p14.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "phone",
            price: 1645,
            numInStock: 11,
            brand: "Samsung",
            rating: 4.9,
            numReviews: 1020,
            description: "High quality"
        },
        {
            
            name: "Samsung s5",
            image: "../images/p15.jpg",
            category: "electronic",
            subCategory: "phone",
            price: 1805,
            numInStock: 8,
            brand: "Samsung",
            rating: 4.8,
            numReviews: 115,
            description: "High quality"
        }

    ],
    categories: ["mecanic", "electronic"],
    subCategories: {"electornic":["phone", "pc"]}
};
export default data;
```

```
categoriesModel file:
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const categoriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({tags: [{type: String}]});

const Categories = mongoose.model("Categories", categoriesSchema);
export default Categories;
```

```
categoriesRouter file:
import express from "express";
import data from "../data.js";
import expressAsyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import Categories from "../models/categoriesModel.js";

 const categoriesRouter = express.Router();
categoriesRouter.get("/seed", expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const ourCategories = await Categories.insertMany(data.categories);
    res.send({ourCategories});
    console.log(ourCategories)
}));
export default categoriesRouter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using await, try using the callback to catch any errors when inserting the documents.

```
const categoriesRouter = express.Router();
 categoriesRouter.get("/seed", expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    Categories.insertMany(data.categories, (err, docs) => {
     if(!err) {
      res.send({docs});
      console.log(docs);
     }else {
       console.log(err);
     }
    });
    
}));
```

Comment: it didin't work for me when i open mongodb and check my database I didn't found the new collection categories.

Comment: @BorhenKalboussi Were any errors logged to the node console?

Comment: when i search data in postman it return me this kind of error "{
    "message": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: myshop.products index: name_1 dup key: { name: \"Aprilia sr 101\" }"
}

Comment: @BorhenKalboussi I believe E11000 means that somewhere you've set unique to true on a field but trying to enter a duplicate value. Not sure why it's applying here. What route are you sending request to?

Comment: note that i added the categories array not in the first time like the other items I had recall it in the last time so I added after doing the other router like usersRouter, productRouter.

Comment: @BorhenKalboussi sorry I don't quite understand your response. I have a feeling you're not sending to this route because the code here looks OK.... I think.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english friend.yes that's exactly the fault my friend, i had discover yesterday.it's a mistake of path.

Comment: @BorhenKalboussi no problem man, I'm glad you figured it out. Happy coding!